# Class Firebase\JWT\JWT not found

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I want to use pure [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library in my code. Firstly, I go to `/var/www/html/` and like the official library page is suggesting, I do this

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

After I run this command, I see that a new vendor folder is created inside `/var/www/html/` with a lot of files and subfolders. I then create my `token.php` file right in `/var/www/html/` with contents similar to that from the official page:

```
<?php
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$key = "example_key";
$token = array(
    "iss" => "http://example.org",
    "aud" => "http://example.com",
    "iat" => 1356999524,
    "nbf" => 1357000000
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

print_r($decoded);
```

However, when I go to *localhost/token.php*, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Firebase\JWT\JWT' not found in /var/www/html/token.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/token.php on line 12

I'm not sure if it matters, but my PHP version is 7.0.

Comment: What do you mean by all this? And why does not official receipt work?

Comment: So, if I use `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`, will it work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), you need to include the autoloader.

E.g., in your php file:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

But... typically your `vendor` folder would be **at the same level** than your `html` folder (the one where you are serving content).

E.g.:

```
- Project root
--- vendor
--- html
----- index.php
```

Then in your index.php you'd do:

```
 require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

It is nice that you trying to use composer and modules, but if I were you I'd try to read on a bit about php's [autoloading features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), so you understand what's going on, and how you can profit from them.

Comment: In my case you dont need to use use \Firebase\JWT\JWT; if you use require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

Answer (score 8):

If not using composer for maintaining the structure. just remove

```
namespace Firebase\JWT;
use \DomainException;
use \InvalidArgumentException;
use \UnexpectedValueException;
use \DateTime;

* 
* JSON Web Token implementation, based on this spec:
* https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519
 *
* PHP version 5
*
* @category Authentication
* @package  Authentication_JWT
* @author   Neuman Vong <neuman@twilio.com>
* @author   Anant Narayanan <anant@php.net>
* @license  http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause 3-clause BSD
* @link     https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
```

form your JWT.php file. It works fine for me know.

Answer (score 4):

I added only one line to your code to get my code to work:

```
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

/* the rest of your code after this */
```

I did not have to modify the jwt.php file at all.

Comment: HI !
Il 'up' the topic as I found same issue, working with an MVC:<br/>
My controller,which uses other composer loaded classes, has the following:<br/>
`use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;`<br/>
and still this `$token=JWT::encode($tokenArray,$secret);` will give same above mentionned error !

Answer (score 2):

depends whether you are using composer or not, 
in case of not using composer try to remove the use part:

```
namespace Firebase\JWT;
use \DomainException;
use \InvalidArgumentException;
use \UnexpectedValueException;
use \DateTime;
```

and if you are using composer make sure your autoloader if loaded

Answer (score 0):

When I don't use composer, I just load all JWT classes in my entry point PHP file, and later, use the main namespace in the classes than have to use JWT. For example, in my index.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/jwt/JWT.php';
require_once 'vendor/jwt/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'vendor/jwt/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'vendor/jwt/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'vendor/jwt/JWK.php';

//Namespaces
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

In a Auth.php class file:

```
//Import the Namespace again
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

I don't really know if it's the correct way to do it when you don't have autoloader file, usually very small projects, but it works for me and possibly someone else is dealing with this too. However, I recognize that the best way to do this is to install the composer :)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this recently. The problem seems to be a conflict in the namespaces somewhere. Solution; I copied the JWT classes into my local libraries folder (*App/Libraries*) and imported from that using `App\Libraries\JWT` namespace. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code.I thik it will work properly

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$key = "example_key";
$token = array(
    "iss" => "http://example.org",
    "aud" => "http://example.com",
    "iat" => 1356999524,
    "nbf" => 1357000000
);
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
print_r($decoded);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).