# Class 'Firebase\Jwt\Jwt' not found YII2

Tags: firebase, yii2, jwt

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt:^2.2
```

install is OK

So

```
    use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
    $key = "example_key";
    $payload = array(
        "iss" => "http://example.org",
        "aud" => "http://example.com",
        "iat" => 1356999524,
        "nbf" => 1357000000
    );
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);
```

Error

**Class 'Firebase\Jwt\Jwt' not found**

Help me!!!

Detail Error

[Dettaglio Errore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHyNz.jpg)

Thank You

Comment: we expect you to do some research before asking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class Firebase\JWT\JWT not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795034/class-firebase-jwt-jwt-not-found)

Comment: This solution dosen't work. I work with YII2 Framework

Comment: Show us your entire error and stack, check if you have the folder into vendor

Answer (score 1):

The code in index.php doesn't look like code you wrote here. Try to `use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;` in index.php.
Also PHP namespaces are case sensitive, so make sure you wrote it correct or use IDE's autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

namespace `Firebase\Authentication;`

You can use this on this file path for crating this file path object.

```
src/public/firebase/php-jwt/Authentication/JWT.php
```